# Query based on calculated fields with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I want to implement a scope `overdue` in a model `Invoice` to return all invoices that exceeded the date, until they had to be paid. I have the fields `invoice_date, :type => Date` and `days_for_payment, :type => Integer`.

In my previous version, which was built on ActiveRecord, I could use the query

```
Invoice.where("invoice_date + days_for_payment < ?", Date.today)
```

This query made the calculation on the DB side.

Is there a way to get the same thing done with Mongoid? Or does anyone know a good workaround (proc, lambda, etc.)?

I use mongoid '2.4.12'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. With the prefix `this.*` I can reference to the fields. And I can use JavaScript functions. MongoDB gets cooler and cooler!

So here is my solution:

```
class Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :invoice_date, :type => Date
  field :days_for_payment, :type => Integer
  ...

  scope :overdue, where("(Math.round(this.invoice_date.getTime() / 1000) + (this.days_for_payment * 24 * 3600)) < #{Time.now.to_i}")

  ...
end
```

Timestamp creation in js works different. So I had to get rid of the last three numbers and round them.
If anybody knows a more elegant way, please let me know.

My only problem left is, that I can't store a `Date` object to MongoDB. It always tells me I have to use `Time`. I think I better upgrade mongoid to 3.0.1.

Comment: There is no more elegant way for manipulating dates in JS. Everything is in milliseconds since epoch. But, in your particular case, as you store `:invoice_date` and `:days_for_payment`, you could use a `before_validation` or `before_save` callback that store the `:overdue_date` : this will be more efficient as you could query normally, meaning with an index (and also range query).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about [mongoid](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria#where-instance_method), if you are querying mongodb directly you can use the [$where operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D).  It is not recommended as it doesn't use indexes.  If you have another condition that filters the records to a small set then you can use the $where to further filter it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've found the solution on my own! [Here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457031/query-based-on-calculated-fields-with-mongoid/11458328#11458328)